# Confused about how lists or os.listdir() work in Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I got the following codes and the way lists or the method os.listdir() work is strange :

**1.**

```
import os
print(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'))
```

Returns :

```
['AAIT.txt', 'AAL.txt', 'AAME.txt', 'AAOI.txt', 'AAON.txt', 'AAPL.txt', 'AAVL.txt', 'AAWW.txt' ....
```

As expected it's single list containing all the files names.

---

**2.**

```
import os
for filenames in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filenames)
```

Returns :

```
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAIT.txt
AAL.txt
AAL.txt
```

It prints every name file eight times. Why is that, `filenames` is a list it should print the entire list just like the previous case as many times as there are files in my folder.

---

**3.**

```
import os
for filenames in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
```

Returns :

```
A
A
I
T
.
t
x
t
A
A
...
```

One caracter per line, it's very odd why is that ? I would expect THIS code to work the way I want, namely to print one file name per line.

How can I get python to print one file name per line ?

Comment: Example 2 print the complete list in the print statement, ie: print(filenames)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *example 2* you are printing the *resulting filename* exactly as many times as there are characters in the filename:

```
for filenames in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filenames)
```

Here `filenames` is **one filename**. Looping over that filename gives you individual characters, bound to `filename` (singular), but you then print `filenames` (*plural*) for each:

```
>>> for foo in ('bar', 'bazbaz'):
...     for character in foo:
...         print(character, foo)
b bar
a bar
r bar
b bazbaz
a bazbaz
z bazbaz
b bazbaz
a bazbaz
z bazbaz
```

I added the `character` print here to illustrate what is going on. A filename with 8 characters is printed 8 times, a filename with 7 characters (such as `'AAL.txt'`) is printed 7 times, etc.

In *example 3* you are just printing the individual characters.

*Remove* the extra loop, you don't need it. Just loop over the values of `os.listdir()`:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: you are right i didn't notice there was a nested loop